# Function that can evaluate multiple games of Rock Paper Scissors at once (using map)

Tags: haskell

I have a Function that evaluates the outcome of a single game of rock paper scissors, and returns the players' name like so:

```
data Symbol = Rock | Paper | Scissors deriving (Eq, Show)
data Outcome = P1 | P2 | Draw deriving (Eq, Show)
evalTurn :: Symbol -> Symbol -> Outcome
evalTurn Rock Scissors = P1
evalTurn Rock Paper = P2
evalTurn Rock Rock = Draw
evalTurn Paper Rock = P1
evalTurn Paper Scissors = P2
evalTurn Paper Paper = Draw
evalTurn Scissors Paper = P1
evalTurn Scissors Rock = P2
evalTurn Scissors Scissors = Draw

type PlayerName = String

data Hand = H PlayerName Symbol deriving (Show)

evalHand :: Hand -> Hand -> Maybe PlayerName
evalHand (H x y) (H a b)
 | evalTurn y b == P1 = Just x
 | evalTurn y b == P2 = Just a
 | evalTurn y b == Draw = Nothing
```

The above `evalHand` function works for one game, however my goal is to write an `evalMatch` function that is able to take an input like this:

```
  evalMatch [ (H "A" Paper, H "B" Rock )
            , (H "A" Rock , H "B" Paper)
            , (H "A" Rock , H "B" Rock )]
```

and return the results in a list.:

```
  == [ Just "A", Just "B",Nothing]
```

This is what I have so far, but my usage of the map function seems to be off. I'd appreciate it if anyone could guide me in the right direction.

```
evalMatch :: [(Hand, Hand)] -> [Maybe PlayerName]
evalMatch [(H x y, H a b)]
 | evalTurn y b == P1 = [Just x]
 | evalTurn y b == P2 = [Just a]
 | evalTurn y b == Draw = [Nothing]
evalMatch ((H x y, H a b):xs) = map evalMatch [x:xs]
```

Comment: `[x:xs]` is a list of length one, whose only element is `x:xs`. `map f [x:xs]` is therefore equal to `[f (x:xs)]`, another list of length one. I don't think this is what you want. You probably intended to write `map f (x:xs)`. (This is not the only issue in your code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a function `evalHand :: Hand -> Hand -> Maybe PlayerName`. One can make use of [**`uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) to convert a function that takes two parameters, here `evalHand` into a function that takes a 2-tuple and returns the result by calling the function with the two items of the 2-tuple.

You thus can implement an `evalMatch` with:

```
evalMatch :: [(Hand, Hand)] -> [Maybe PlayerName]
evalMatch = map (…)
```

where I leave filling in the `…` part as an exercise. This expression should work with `uncurry` and `evalHand`.

Comment: I haven't heard of `uncurry` before, thank you for the insight! I didn't end up using `map` for my solution, but your answer was super helpful nonetheless.